# Trying to read a txt file and store it into an array list within a multi-value hash-map

Tags: java, arraylist, hash, key

i have a text file and it looks something like this:

```
gui awtui   swingui
swingui runner  extensions
textui  runner  framework
awtui   runner
runner  framework
extensions  framework
```

*They are seperated by a tab*

I am storing these using a hash map with keys is the first line and value is the the rest of characters within that line for e.g.
key = gui value = atwui swingui

I therefore used a one key, multi-valued hash-map to achieve this and this is what i have done so far.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PackageAnalyser {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    HashMap<String, List<String>> dependencies = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> pack = new ArrayList<String>();    
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))){
            //String line = null;
            while ((in.hasNext() )){
                String [] packs = in.nextLine().split("\t");
                for (int i = 0; i < packs.length; i++){
                    pack.add(packs[i]);
                    Arrays.sort(packs);
                } 
                dependencies.put(packs[0], pack);
                }

            }catch (IOException ex){
                System.err.println(ex);
            } finally {
        }System.out.println(dependencies);
    }
}
```

After several attempts modifying the code, this is what the output looks like when i run it

```
`{awtui = [awtui, swingui, runner, swingui, runner, textui, runner, framework, framework], framework=[awtui, swingui, runner, swingui, textui, runner, framework, framework], extensions=[awtui, swingui, runner, swingui, runner, textui, runner, framework, framework]}
```

the output that i wanted is:

```
{gui = [awtui, swingui], swingui = [runner, extensions], textui =[runner, framework], awtui = [runner], runner = [framework], extensions = [framework]}
```

As shown as i am reading from a text file and i wanted to show as the output above has shown. please help.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class PackageAnalyser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HashMap<String, SortedSet<String>> dependencies = new HashMap<String, SortedSet<String>>();

        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]))) {
            while ((in.hasNext())) {
                String[] packs = in.nextLine().split("\\s");
                String key = packs[0];

                SortedSet<String> deps = dependencies.get(key);
                if (deps == null) {
                    deps = new TreeSet<String>();
                    dependencies.put(key, deps);
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < packs.length; i++) {
                    if (!packs[i].equals("")) {
                        deps.add(packs[i]);                 
                    }
                }                
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        } finally {
        }
        System.out.println(dependencies);
    }
}
```

gives `{extensions=[framework], textui=[framework, runner], gui=[awtui, swingui], swingui=[extensions, runner], awtui=[runner], runner=[framework]}`

If you want to preserve the order of insertions, you can use `LinkedHashMap` instead of a plain `HashMap`

Comment: thank you. these are new topics in java to me, ill explore the linkedhashmap :)

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, you are adding the whole list to your values, rather than throwing out the first value.

Second, throw the sort out, or move it.  You are sorting it, THEN storing the first value.  This will likely mess up your order and use the wrong key.

Finally, it looks like pack is never cleared.  After each loop, pack needs to be a new arraylist, or have it's values cleared

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you were trying to sort to preserve read-order. But here's a relatively shorter piece of code :

```
package com.demo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PackageAnalyser {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            String line = null;
            String[] lineParts = null;

            HashMap<String, List<String>> dependencies = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                line = scanner.nextLine();
                lineParts = line.split("\\s+");

                dependencies.put(lineParts[0], Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(lineParts, 1, lineParts.length)));
            }

            System.out.println(dependencies);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

gives

> {gui=[awtui, swingui], swingui=[runner, extensions], textui=[runner,
>   framework], awtui=[runner], runner=[framework],
>   extensions=[framework]}